# Trouble Removing Login Button from Server Using MenuContributor in ABP Framework

Tags: c#, abp

Does anyone know how to remove the login button from the AuthServer?  I thought it would be part of the MenuContributor, but it's not.

[image]

It is weird because according to this doc, we can add a menu item with contributor:

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/AspNetCore/Navigation-Menu

And it works; it adds the items you want, but if you want to remove one, there is only one method for that called:

```
context.Menu.TryRemoveMenuItem("Login");
```

That not works, but if you look at the current items on the menu, it only returns one item called:

```
Abp.Application.Main.Administration
```

That menu item does not exist on my navbar, and the login or language items are not there.

How can I remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marked area is not rendering from menu contributors. It comes from toolbar contributors. You should update the main toolbar.

Here is the documentation: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/AspNetCore/Customization-User-Interface#toolbar-contributors

---

Alternatively, you can override the UserLoginLink component, which is responsible to add login link to toolbar: https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/modules/account/src/Volo.Abp.Account.Web/Modules/Account/Components/Toolbar/UserLoginLink/Default.cshtml

Here is the documentation that show you how to override a view component: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/AspNetCore/Customization-User-Interface#overriding-a-view-component